# Creating report in PDF with images from python

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation

I want to make a PDF with report from the python plots I have made.

I am importing those images to pdf with the following lines:

```
import os
import img2pdf
with open("report.pdf", "wb") as f:
        f.write(img2pdf.convert([i for i in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\rysza\\Desktop\\python data analysis\\zajecia5') if i.endswith(".jpg")]))
```

My question is how can I create additional page in front of the images where I can put some text.

I was trying with this, but seems not to be working:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
c = canvas.Canvas("report.pdf")
c.drawString(100,750,"Welcome to Reportlab!")
```

Any options are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `fpdf` lib

here you can find code examples here
https://python-scripts.com/create-pdf-pyfpdf
(also you can translate page to english with https://translate.yandex.ru/translate )